# How to import a package from SSMS to Visual Studio for local machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ssis, ssms

I'm trying to mess around with an SSIS package on my local machine. Currently, this package is in SSMS under a server. When I try to export this package, save it on my desktop and doule-click to open it, a deployment wizard comes up.

What I want, is the package to be stored as a project file which can opened from Visual Studio. Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Creating a new project in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and import
   the project from existing catalog.
2. Exporting the project into ispac file via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

For detailed steps visit http://www.mssqlgirl.com/editing-published-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012.html